# MS Sync Framework overwrite/ignore new insert from different users?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I implemented a SQL Server Sync program using Sync2.1 framework. It is supposed to be used by multiple users: 
1) Master DB is installed on server MyServer.com;
2) Each user is provisioned using the same schema and scope;
3) User A sync the server, no change.
4) User B sync the server, no change.
5) User B makes changes, Sync the server, it shows 1 change upload and 0 change download;
6) Now, if Use A make changes, Sync the server, it shows 1 change upload, but with XXXXXX changes download, XXXXXX is a big #.

I thought after step #4, no matter who sync the database, only the changes will be uploaded or downloaded. But it looks like after an user sync, if there is another user sync, then when the 1st user sync again, it will download the entire database as changes again.

Is this normal? What can cause this? Or, maybe Sync is supposed to be used by one user only? or, different users should use different Schemas?

Furthermore, in the DB, it has a table 'Location', which has a column LocationId (PK), and it is auto INT. There is another table 'Client', it has a column 'LocationId' pointing to Location table, and has a ClientId column (PK). Now, user A work on local DB, insert a new Location whose LocationID = 100, and insert a new Client, whose ClientId = 123. User A sync to the server. But before that, User B also work on local DB, insert a new Location whose LocationID = 100, and insert a new Client, whose ClientId = 123. Now, if User B sync to the server, I thought on the server, it will have 2 new rows, 1 row from User A and 1 row from User B since there are 2 inserts. However, it only has 1 new row, LocationId = 100, and ClientId = 123. Is this supposed to be? is it because after User A and B insert on their local DB, they all have the new row LocationId = 100 which is the PK?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some code how you're provisioning and synching? as to the PK issue, if your clients both insert the same PK value, you can't have duplicate PKs on the central copy. whichever syncs to the server first will be the record in the server. the second one to sync will encounter a conflict and you will have to resolve which one to take, the server copy or the client copy. you should avoid using identity columns as PKs when synchronizing. Whether you use Sync Framework or not, that will cause PK value collisions when you try to copy them to a central database.

Comment: So basically Sync framework does is to use PK to decide whether there is insert/update/delete? If so, then we have to use GUID for PK, or somehow track the transaction instead of PK (could be very complex).

Comment: how will it know which row to apply an update or a delete if it cannot uniquely identify a row? :) the insert/update/deletes are tracked via triggers and change tracking is stored in the _tracking tables.

Comment: What we did is to have a device ID be the first few digits of every ID, then we don't have performance hit of GUID's. There is a device table with deviceID matching up to @@SERVERNAME (we manually have to make sure each machine name is unique. Ex. device 1 is rows 0010000000 to 0019999999

Comment: that's exactly what we did. for each user who uses the software, there is an userId, So, basically we split the BIGINT into blocks of 10,000,000. So, user 1 uses 1-10,000,000; user 2 uses 10,000,001 - 20,000,000, .... although we have to change the code a little, it works fine for the Sync framework.